# I am trying to open a .dat file as a pandas data frame in python with unknown encoding The file opens in the required format in Excel,

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding, character-encoding

I want to open  .dat file as a pandas dataframe.It is opening perfectly in excel.

I have tried multiple encoding.
Contents of DAT file below

Á 2                     TYPE       C                  DESCRIPTIO C                  START      N                   NEXT       N&                  ADD        N,
  GENERAL(COMP)                      1     1300000 AGODOWN BILLS                       1     1100000

excel file link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OOVaR-Sw937kr4HSjbE3UNJdS9i_wzKD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You should upload some code what you have tried so far, it will help others to find the issue.

Comment: What's this got to do with FoxPro? And no, .DAT is not a FoxPro extension.